# How to get the count of duplicate value for all columns of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this,

```
dept_no | employee_id 
1       | 001
1       | 002
2       | 003
2       | 004
```

I want to get values like this:

```
field_name | count_of_distinct_value
dept_no    | 2
employee_id| 4
```

I know how to get the count of distinct value for a certain field, but don't know how to get for all columns at a time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select key, count(distinct value)
from (select (jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t.*))).* from pg_class as t) as tt
group by key;
```

It is definitely not the most efficient solution but it is applicable for any table. Just replace `pg_class` by the desired table name.

PS: I got a lot of pain proposing this solution. Imagine the table with 100M rows and 100 columns. Then PostgreSQL should to build and sort the intermediate data with 10000000000 rows.

If you don't want the exact numbers but only evaluative then look at the [`pg_stats`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html) table at the `n_distinct` column in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest method is `union all`:

```
select 'dept_no' as colname, count(distinct dept_no)
from t
union all
select 'employee_id' as colname, count(distinct employee_id)
from t;
```

Unpivoting and aggregating is another possible solution.  But it probably has slightly worse performance and requires converting the columns to a string (a common type):

```
select colname, count(distinct val)
from t cross join lateral
    (values ('dept_no', dept_no::text), ('employee_id', employee_id)
     ) v(colname, val)
group by colname;
```

Or better, in one pass:

```
select
    colname,
    count_of_distinct_value
from (
    select
        count(distinct dept_no) as dept_no,
        count(distinct employee_id) as employee_id
    from t) ....
```

Comment: when the table name changed, the fields changed,

Comment: Usually "aggregate then unpivot" more efficient then "unpivote then aggregate".

Comment: @Abelisto . . . Your solution is better anyway; there is no need to list the columns (which is why I upvoted it).

Comment: My solution is bad definitely. Just imagine the table with 100M rows and 100 columns. `pg_stat` could be useful here but not